# Automatically going to the first page in a hierarchy?

Tags: menus, templates

Let's say I have a website about different types of cars. The structure is a little like this:

```
-Home
-Cars (shows a submenu with a list of cars, ie Volvo 850, Porsche 911 )
 -Volvo 850 overview (the page you get when you click Volvo 850 on the Car page)
 -Volvo 850 tech spec (the three Volvo pages are shown as submenu links on any Volvo page)
 -Volvo 850 pictures
 -Porsche 911 overview
 -Porsche 911 tech spec
 -Porsche 911 pictures
```

What's the best way of doing this? I guess what I'm asking is how to **automatically** make the Cars page list the different Cars, and link to the overview page and not the others. And then on the individual car pages, have more sub-menus for overview, tech spec, and pictures page.

I could have a structure like this:

```
-Cars (shows a submenu with a list of cars, ie Volvo 850, Porsche 911 )
 -Volvo 850
  -Volvo 850 overview (the page you get when you click Volvo 850 on the Car page)
  -Volvo 850 tech spec (the three Volvo pages are shown as submenu links on any Volvo page)
  -Volvo 850 pictures
```

.. but I don't want that intermediate Volvo 850 page to show, because there would be nothing on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing the [wp_list_pages function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages)

You'll probably need to use the second structure you listed, with one change:

```
-Cars (shows a submenu with a list of cars, ie Volvo 850, Porsche 911 )
 -Volvo 850 overview (the page you get when you click Volvo 850 on the Car page)
  -Volvo 850 tech spec (the three Volvo pages are shown as submenu links on any Volvo page)
  -Volvo 850 pictures
```

I think the following may work, although it might show all descendants (rather than immediate children only):

```
<?php
  if($post->post_parent)
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->post_parent."&echo=0");
  else
  $children = wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=".$post->ID."&echo=0");
  if ($children) { ?>
  <ul>
  <?php echo $children; ?>
  </ul>
  <?php } ?>
```

Your statement

> And then on the individual car pages,
>   have more sub-menus for overview, tech
>   spec, and pictures page.

Seems contradictory to not wanting an 'intermediate' page, since you said you want the "overview" page to be what you land on when clicking on a car model on the cars page. If you just want all pages related to the Volvo 850 to have a listing of Volvo 850 pages (for instance, in the sidebar), you could possibly use [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#List_parent_Page_and_all_descendant_Pages):

```
<?php 
// use wp_list_pages to display parent and all child pages all generations (a tree with parent)
$parent = 93;
$args=array(
  'child_of' => $parent
);
$pages = get_pages($args);  
if ($pages) {
  $pageids = array();
  foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $pageids[]= $page->ID;
  }

  $args=array(
    'title_li' => 'Tree of Parent Page ' . $parent,
    'include' =>  $parent . ',' . implode(",", $pageids)
  );
  wp_list_pages($args);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You asked a very similar and related question in [*"Same Custom Fields spanning several pages?"*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/858/same-custom-fields-spanning-several-pages/) and I think your answer is really the same:

- [**Use Custom Post Types and configure your URLs accordingly**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/858/same-custom-fields-spanning-several-pages/873#873).