# "Author" custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, author

I have an existing WP site where there is a custom post type called Author with a few hundred entries. I need to create a single entry page from these authors, but single-author.php just returns a 404.
I know Author is a reserved keyword in WP and it shouldn't be used for custom post type names. Both WP user single entry page and custom post type author is redirecting to /author/nicename slug and both just return 404. I am not able to change the custom post type name unfortunately. Is there a work around this?

Comment: Why can't you change it? Clearly your site is broken as a direct result of the term being reserved.

Comment: Because there are already a few hundred "authors" and these have been assigned to a few thousand posts as a post object and displayed on the single post pages.

Comment: I think the reason why the site was (possibly) created this way is to differentiate the external authors from the WP users. Now I need to find a work around this.

Comment: I'd say that renaming your post type will be easier and safer in the long run that any hacky workaround that could break on the next WP update.

Comment: See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/renaming-custom-post-types-and-taxonomies