# Is it possible to list post attachments in a sub URL endpoint with a dedicated template?

Tags: permalinks, attachments, templates

Wordpress provides templates for displaying media attached to a post or page (`attachment.php` and more). They're also displayed with nice permalinks, such as:

```
site.com/projects/a-project/an-attachment/
```

Where `projects` is the slug for my custom post type `project`. `a-project` is the post name, and `an-attachment` is the name of an attached image.

**The functionality I'm asking for is a sub URL endpoint for listing all post attachments with a dedicated template file.** It would be great with a permalink for a post's attachments, wouldn't it?

Such as:

```
site.com/projects/a-project/attachments/
or
site.com/projects/a-project/images/
```

Is it possible? If not with pretty permalinks, is it with some kind of query variable? Apart from showing a single attachment, I haven't ever seen another form of sub URL endpoint to a Wordpress post before.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Some interesting resources:

http://johnbeales.com/20090824/endpoints-a-little-secret-for-url-manipulation-in-wordpress/

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-rewrite-approach-with-add_rewrite_endpoint

http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/

http://codex.wordpress.org/User:DavidHouse/WP_Rewrite_API

[URL Design for Sub-Posts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/url-design-for-sub-posts)

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it myself. Now I've successfully managed to add a `/photos` endpoint to a permalink URL, such as:

```
http://mywordpressite.com/projects/a-project/photos
```

And then a custom template, `photos.php` will load and show – with access to the global `$post` variable.

Helpful links:

- http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

In my `functions.php` I added functions for the `single_template` and `query_vars` filters and added a `photos` endpoint with the handy `add_rewrite_endpoint()` function.

```
// Permalink rewrites/add endpoints
add_filter( 'single_template', 'project_attachments_template' );
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars');

// You may need to go to wp-admin > Settings > Permalinks and 
// save the changes in order to flush rewrite rules to activate.
add_rewrite_endpoint('photos', EP_PERMALINK);
```

Further down in the file:

```
/**
*   Add the 'photos' query variable so Wordpress
*   won't mangle it.
*/
function add_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = "photos";
    return $vars;
}


/**
*   From http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy
*
*   Adds a custom template to the query queue.
*/
function project_attachments_template($templates = ""){
    global $wp_query;

    // If the 'photos' endpoint isn't appended to the URL,
    // don't do anything and return
    if(!isset( $wp_query->query['photos'] ))
        return $templates;

    // .. otherwise, go ahead and add the 'photos.php' template
    // instead of 'single-{$type}.php'.
    if(!is_array($templates) && !empty($templates)) {
        $templates = locate_template(array("photos.php", $templates),false);
    } 
    elseif(empty($templates)) {
        $templates = locate_template("photos.php",false);
    }
    else {
        $new_template = locate_template(array("photos.php"));
        if(!empty($new_template)) array_unshift($templates,$new_template);
    }

    return $templates;
}
```

Be sure to visit the Permalink page in wp-admin for the changes to take effect.

Comment: This worked really well for me as a mu-plugin, except I had to hook the `add_rewrite_endpoint` function into `init`. Thanks for sharing the code!