# How to have this permalink structure: post_type/postname/custom_inner_page

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, theme-development, permalinks

Imagine I have a custom post type called City with custom related meta.

The following is working just fine:

```
mysite.com/city/new-york/
```

However, I would like to have an "inner" page listing stuff related to that post in the following way:

```
mysite.com/city/new-york/stores
```

Inside of which I would query for something like

```
post_type='stores',
category='new-york'
```

If an editor adds another city it should work with no additional coding.

And then hopefully have posts linked as:

```
mysite.com/city/new-york/stores/apple
```

I've been searching for this for a while and still haven't figured it out. Maybe I'm approaching it the wrong way.

Asfar as I know, mysite.com/city/new-york can't be a custom taxonomy because I need it to be a full featured page, with meta boxes and featured image.

Answer (score 0):

Register your [taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) first and set the argument slug and rewrite rules to your slug which is city

Register your post type with `slug` of your taxonomy city prefixed and make sure you set the `has_archive` argument to taxonomy.

Now add a [filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_type_link) to `post_type_link` to make the stores show the individual permalink.

```
register_post_type(
    'city',
    array(
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'city/%stores%', 'with_front' => false ),
       'has_archive' => 'city',
       // additional args
    )
);


register_taxonomy(
  'stores',
  'city',
   array(
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'city', 'with_front' => false ),
    // your other args...
)
);

function yourprefix_store_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
  if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'city' ){
      $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'stores' );
      if( $terms ){
          return str_replace( '%stores%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
      }
  }
  return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'yourprefix_store_permalinks', 1, 2 );
```

*Use built-in Tools Generating WP Stuff here at [GenrateWP](https://generatewp.com/)*

Hope this is what you are looking for. If not you can read about similar article by [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199456/custom-taxonomy-post-slug-permalink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post)

Comment: Did as you said and it's now `mysite.com/city/%stores%/new-york` and `mysite.com/city/stores/new-york` when it should be `mysite.com/city/new-york/` and `mysite.com/city/new-york/stores` respectively. Thanks a lot for the effort though

Comment: What are the following can you please correct again so that I can cross-check and try `city / new-york / stores / ` I think City is a PostType and New York is a City / stores is a single post.

Comment: `city` is indeed a post type. `new-york`, though, is a single post of such post type and `stores` should be some kind of "taxonomy" linking to a page where I could list anything related to `new-york`. I think I finally found a way to do it: [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37895/is-it-possible-to-list-post-attachments-in-a-sub-url-endpoint-with-a-dedicated-t)

Comment: Glad you got it working. Anyway if you post how you got it. then it will be helpful for others too.